# Screen is completely white!

Tags: technical-issues, macos, monitor, roblox

I have played Roblox for years and recently my dad purchased me and my sister new Mac Book Pro's. I was extremely excited for this new laptop because on my old one Roblox had not worked. I download Roblox and clicked join game, but the game itself is completely white! I can hear all of the game sounds, and it also says that I am playing the game. I have uninstalled and redownloaded it, and have searched the web for a solution, but have came up empty-handed. I have found one video, except the person was not using a mac book, so the video was no help to me. It works perfectly fine on my sister's laptop, so I am giving up hope on mine.

Comment: almost all MacBooks now have two video cards (GPUs). Games should generally use Discrete GPU, so you can check if your Roblox is actually using it - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202053

Answer (score -1):

Is Roblox the only game with this problem? Try playing other games to test this.

You could try to restart your computer, or even system reset it because it may be a problem with game visuals. If that doesn't work, or you don't want to do it, you could uninstall Roblox, wait a few days (I suggest a week) and then reinstall it again. The time game between the uninstallation and installation may help to give the new installed version a more steady launch pad to run on your computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).